# How to configure SNMP trap multi-casting server

Tags: snmp, ubuntu-14.04, net-snmp

I would like to know if there is a way of configuring SNMP trap multicast server?
I have configured central SNMP manager on Ubuntu 14.04 and it is receiving SNMP traps. Now I want to send the same traps received to the first SNMP manager to multiple SNMP managers in different locations.